# Singular or Plural Use of One Object in Two Locations

Tags: grammatical-number

Should *grand opening* be singular or plural? The sentences in question:

> Celebrate the grand ***opening*** of Planet Fitness Mason and Planet
>   Fitness Middletown for just one dollar!

or

> Celebrate the grand ***openings*** of Planet Fitness Mason and Planet
>   Fitness Middletown for just one dollar!

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd is grammatically accurate, but the 1st certainly works well enough colloquially and feels more comfortable, and in advertising the comfort of the target - the bulk of whom are not grammarians - is significant.

Also, they both leave open the implication that the "*one dollar*" gets you the ability to access *both* locations for $1 (that may be true, I don't know how it works) and it could be read to mean that the *celebrator* ought to be able to be at *both* locations simultaneously.

I'd suggest different wording altogether (and, in my example below, with the added benefit of repeating the name one more time).

"**Celebrate the grand opening of Planet Fitness at either of our new locations - Planet Fitness Mason or Planet Fitness Middletown - for just $1!!!**"

If brevity is not necessary:

Celebrate the spectacular grand opening of Planet Fitness at either of our new, state of the art, convenient locations - Planet Fitness in Mason with its stunning array of Spirit Fitness CT850 treadmills, or the largest collection of Bodycraft weight lifting cages in the city at Planet Fitness Middletown - all for just $1!!! (note: I have no idea what equipment they use, I just cut and pasted a google search of exercise machines.)

Okay that's a bit ridiculous. But so is advertising, right? I'm hearing the voice of a fast talking huckster in my head...

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler answer: It is a grand opening if it is a single event, even if it is held in two locations; in this case your $1 should grant you access to either or both locations. They are grand openings if they are separate events, whether simultaneous or not.